# geemap.requireJS can't access code in EE asset

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, geemap

I'm trying to access a package from the 'users/gena/packages:grid' using geemap.requireJS() function with this code:

```
import ee
import geemap

ee.Initialize()
lib = geemap.requireJS('users/gena/packages:text')
lib
```

When the code runs, an auth window pops (somewhat unexpected):

[image]

So I enter my username and password. But it doesn't work. I'm getting this error message in the terminal:

```
Cloning into 'packages'...
remote: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument
remote: [type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.LocalizedMessage]
remote: locale: "en-US"
remote: message: "Invalid authentication credentials. Please generate a new identifier: https://earthengine.googlesource.com/new-password"
remote:
remote: request_id: "59346ac7688f4beb928ebbd9c63438a6"
fatal: unable to access 'https://earthengine.googlesource.com/users/gena/packages/': The requested URL returned error: 400
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\guilherme.castro\...\testing.py", line 8, in <module>
    lib = geemap.requireJS('users/gena/packages:grid')
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guilherme.castro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\geemap\common.py", line 13036, in requireJS
    lib_path = change_require(lib_path)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\guilherme.castro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\geemap\common.py", line 13096, in change_require
    raise ValueError(f"{lib_path} does not exist.")
ValueError: packages/grid does not exist.
```

Well, I know the repo exists and works once I'm using it in the same code in the JS code editor with:

```
var txt = require('users/gena/packages:text');
```

Following the url given in the error message (https://earthengine.googlesource.com/users/gena/packages/) leads me to a commit list.

What I'm doing wrong here?